# awk/sed output from system_profiler on 10.6.8

Tags: text-editor

If I have:

foo
bar

..and I'd like to awk/sed this to:

foo-bar

..what's the syntax?

I'm trying to use:

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Type/ {print $2} /Speed/ {print $2}'|sed 's/\r$/a\"-"/'
```

to output type-speed (ie DDR-1067).

Comment: If you don't get any sed/awk help here, there are plenty of other sites that address those unix tools explicitly, rather than by extension that a mac program is generating xml output. Just hop in the chat room if you need help selecting a destination or flag it for moderator help if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this sed instead:

```
|sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'
```

system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Type/ {print $2} /Speed/ {print $2}'|sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'

output:

```
DDR3 1066
DDR3 1066
DDR3 1066
Empty Empty
```

Comment: How do you make it stop after the first line though? When I awk using the above command I get: DDR2-667 [carriage return] DDR2-667 I just want the first line.

Comment: Insert an ;exit after /Speed/ {print $2 **,so it would look like:** 

.... /Speed/ {print $2;exit} .....

Answer (score 0):

Awk can easily do this on it's own, like so:

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Type:/ {type=$2} /Speed:/ {speed=$2; printf "%s-%s\n", type, speed}'
```